# MSI Afterburner wrong clock values

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, overclocking

Well, whats worng with MSI Afterburner?
It shows zeros instead of 1085MHz and 1753MHz in Core clock/Memory clock.

In my `.cfg` I added this but it didn't help. I installed new drivers too, didn't help either.

```
[ATIADLHAL]
UnofficialOverclockingEULA = I confirm that I am aware of unofficial overclocking limitations and fully understand that MSI will not provide me any support on it 
UnofficialOverclockingMode = 1
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the software I would report them problem to MSI.

Comment: @Ramhound the funniest thing I get GTX770 from MSI today lol

Comment: You verified your running the current version of the software?  That disk was made and printed months ago

Comment: @Ramhound I downloaded latest version from their website

Comment: @Ramhound I found russian forum and wrote there but is there some MSI Afterburner official bug tracker?

Comment: Why would you post on some random Russian forum?  There is unlikely going to be a bug tracker for that program.

Comment: @Ramhound not random, official MSI forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I get my answers today so I found out that with Msi Afterburner videocards using `nVidia Kepler` architecture output clocks like that.